# shopify_api gem exhibits some new messages

Tags: shopify

Running some code CLI style and I noticed..

```
/Users/fizzy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/shopify_api-3.0.1/lib/shopify_api/json_format.rb:3: warning: method redefined; discarding old encode
/Users/fizzy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activeresource-3.2.8/lib/active_resource/base.rb:1214: warning: previous definition of encode was here
/Users/fizzy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/shopify_api-3.0.1/lib/shopify_api/json_format.rb:13: warning: method redefined; discarding old decode
/Users/fizzy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activeresource-3.2.8/lib/active_resource/formats/json_format.rb:20: warning: previous definition of decode was here
```

and a bunch more... is there a patch coming to address the warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dare say we'll get to it, but if it's really bugging you we accept pull requests on the `shopify_api` repo.